# Bind scope variable with a Javascript object property

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I need to bind a variable with a JS object's property. Is it possible ?

In my controller

```
...
$scope.data = "initial value";
$scope.obj = {data : $scope.data}
...
```

And  in my View

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data">
<h1> {{ obj.data }} </h1>
```

When i update the text in my input box it should update the value in `<h1>` and it should be done **through the object**.

> No functions, No watchers or anything, Just with binding. Is it possible ?

This is my question simplified. what im trying to do is create a object with some changing variables, and pass it to an AngularJS component where it will display the value changes. **I need to pass an object**, not different values individually.

Comment: have you tried `ng-model="obj.data"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind your object with `ng-model`

```
.............
$scope.obj = {data : "initial value"}
................
```

your view

```
<input type="text" ng-model="obj.data">
<h1> {{ obj.data }} </h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **`<input type="text" ng-model="obj.data">`**

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
   $scope.data = "initial value";
   $scope.obj = {data : $scope.data}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="obj.data">
<h1> {{ obj.data }} </h1>
</body>
```

Comment: delete the line `<input type="text" ng-model="obj.data">`, and manipulate `obj.data` through javascript function. will that work?